# Cómo especificar más de 1 url-path-map en el comando de az network application-gateway rule create

Tags: powershell, azure

El comando en cuestión es el siguiente

```
az network application-gateway rule create --gateway-name --name --resource-group [--address-pool] [--http-listener] [--http-settings] [--no-wait {0, 1, f, false, n, no, t, true, y, yes}] [--priority] [--redirect-config] [--rewrite-rule-set] [--rule-type {Basic, PathBasedRouting}] [--url-path-map]
```

Tengo 2 url-path-map llamados `MyPathMap2` y `MyPathMap3`

Pero si quiero que tenga 2 o más rutas no sé cómo modificar el comando para que acepte más de 1 url-path-map.

Según la documentación debo usar el --rule-type PathBasedRouting, entonces para crear la regla con 1 solo path-map uso el comando

```
az network application-gateway rule create --gateway-name --name --resource-group --address-pool --http-listener --http-settings --rule-type PathBasedRouting --url-path-map MyPathMap2 --priority
```